# Why does only small amount of Java libraries contain module-info.class inside?

Tags: java, maven

Why does only small amount of Java libraries contain `module-info.class` inside? I searched through my local Maven repository and from >400 jars only three had `module-info.class` inside (`asm-7.2.jar`, `asm-6.2.jar` and `plexus-java-1.0.5.jar`). Does that mean that Java modularity is not being accepted?

Comment: It is just easier not to use jigsaw, especially with build tools.

Comment: @dan1st Not really the problem...

Comment: *Simple:* Because only a small amount of library authors have upgraded to Java 9+.

Comment: @Andreas You can support JDK9+ but no need to upgrade to JDK9+ (multi release jars is an option but not really easy).

Answer (score 3):

First, the number is a little bit higher see here https://github.com/sormuras/modules apart from that there are two/three aspects of using modules.

- First the library authors must go that way (which is quite often harder than you think; much more separation/reflection etc.). Also, their used libraries must support JDK9+
- A larger number of libraries on the other hand have not yet used modules nor working correctly on higher JDK versions (JDK9+) (which is a point for library authors as well or a circular dependency).
- Finally the acceptance of modules on the user's side.

For some projects, it does not make sense to use modules (yes it has some advantages but no one likes to see that) for example in a spring boot project if you finally package everything into a single jar file because `module-info.java` works only a single jar file level. This is true for so many micro-services etc.

Apart from that, the acceptance of JDK9+ (minimum JDK11) is relatively small in comparison to JDK8 and less than that (unfortunately). Many companies/projects etc. are working on EE containers (old versions of Java) etc. and using libraries.. you see the circle.

And many projects don't like to cut the line from older versions meaning before JDK8 which is thing is very important. The issue is also JDK11 (currently LTS) will be replaced with JDK 17 (Sept. 2021) ... and so the hurdle becomes higher and higher...

Comment: Is there something wrong with https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html solution?

Comment: @VytenisBivainis It is one solution but not the best because that means you have JDK9+ specific parts in the same source location as JDK9- parts which is not supported by any IDE today.. So usually the best would be to separate JDK9+ specific from JDK8 code... the solution is not ideal... I know that...

Answer (score -1):

Because the developers of those libraries used Java 9 or above.

module-info.class is the compiled version of module-info.java, which is a module descriptor. Modules were introduced in Java 9 to add an higher level of organisation above packages.

Comment: This is not related to the question. Apart from that is not correct. You can compile a project with JDK8 and add a Java 9 module-info.java into your project (multi release jars)..